# How to add the SwingFXUtils in module-info.java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using Intellij Idea to create my simple program in javafx that requires SwingFXUtils to convert the image, but I am stuck in this error. I cannot import the SwingFXUtils and I'm trying to add a line of code at module-info.java, but I have no idea what is the right code to put in the module-info.java. What is the right one:

requires javafx....

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Note you can determine the module of a class by looking at [its documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html). Also, if you're using a build tool (e.g., Maven, Gradle, etc.), make sure to configure it to include the `org.openjfx:javafx-swing` dependency (as shown in the answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Maven: add this dependency to your pom.xml and just change the version of your JavaFX version.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are using Gradle: insert this module into the javafx section at build.gradle

```
modules = ['*****', '*****','javafx.swing']
```

After that, add this to your module-info.java and your problem should be fixed

```
requires javafx.swing;
```